# MySQL - Delete using conditions of many columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I wonder whether such query is valid in MySQL, because I tried to run it, but it says I have a SQL syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE (col1, col2) IN (('str1','str2'), ('str3', 'str4'));
```

Comment: The syntax is fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f015104e34152b9894e079a201f0080.

Comment: Please add complete error message.

Comment: Note that although apparently elegant, MySQL is (curiously) unable to use an index against such queries

Comment: could you add more information about your table and your values?

only a query will not explain what want!